# Regex unable to parse version

Tags: regex

My objective is to get the version number from a string where the string may contain anything.  Here's my example data set:

```
Version 1.32.0.1
Version 1.32.0.1c
Version 1.32.1
Version 1.33.2e
Version 1.32
```

I've attempted to match that [with this regex](https://regex101.com/r/WyPGrE/2) `(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\w?)` but I can't seem to figure out why this won't match the 4th decimal value, even with the descriptive breakdown provided by regex101.com.

**What am I misunderstanding about this regex causing it to not match all version variations?**

Comment: What's the language/tool?

Comment: In .NET you can do the following: `string version = Regex(str_version, @"Version\s+(?'ver'.+)").Groups["ver"].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

Count how many `\d+` you have got. You should count 3. So your regex will at most match 3 numbers, and it cannot possibly match 4.

I'm not sure if this is a typo or you genuinely don't understand, but this can be fixed by adding another group:

```
(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)(\w?)
```

This can be shortened to:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}(\w?)
```

If you want to match any number of numbers more than 1, you can do:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)+(\w?)
```

`\w` would match `_` as well. If you don't want that, you can replace it with `[a-z]`.

Comment: You can modify the short version to cover the long version, i.e. max 4 numbers, by using `{1,3}`, as in: `\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}[a-z]?`. I change to use `[a-z]` since OP probably doesn't want to match `_`, which `\w` would.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the comments. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have used `?` in non-capturing group which will match only 3rd decimal value(even if you have 3rd and 4th decimal value present).
One solution would be to use `*` instead of `?` in `non-capturing group` for your non-capturing group to match 3rd as well as 4th decimal value.

I tried in Scala and it works perfectly for your inputs above:

```
  val text: String = "Version 1.32.0.1c"
  val pattern = """(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(\w?)""".r
  val res: Regex.MatchIterator = pattern.findAllIn(text)
  println(res.group(1)) // 1.32.0.1
  println(res.group(2)) // c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, maybe it's the result you want to achieve:

```
\w+[.](\w*[.]?)*
```

In a text block:

```
Version 1_32.0.1
Version 1.32.0.1c
Version 1.32.1
Version 1.33.2e.
Version 1.32
Version e342
```

it matches only version numbers which starts with any alphanumeric characters (and underscores), followed by one dot and in the loop followed by zero or many any of alphanumeric character with dot at the end of a line.

Here is a demo: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/DAKdH9/1/)